# CSS Flexbox Wrap with different Height and Widht's

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to create a Flexbox layout with childs that wrap AND can have **different sizes**?
I've tried alot and even looked for libraries that can do it, but didn't find anything.

**This is an
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xMwK.png) image.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with flex but with grid it is 100% possible !

Comment: And could this grid layout be responsive to different screen sizes?

Comment: Take a look at this library https://masonry.desandro.com/ this could be just what you need

Comment: Yep ! With media queries also in grid it's a simple task to create layouts